# nginx nested subfolders for application in virtualhost

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, subdirectory

I'm trying to run 2 applications on the server...

- first application on the root document (wordpress)
- and second application in a folder /app (symfony4)

The problem is that i an't find the way to use the alias on the nested folder...
my config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;

    server_name ~^(?<folder>[^.]*).magana.dev.hexis.fr;


    charset utf-8;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/projects/dev/magana/$folder/htdocs;
    access_log /var/www/projects/dev/magana/$folder/access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/projects/dev/commons/logs/magana_error.log;

    client_max_body_size 200M;

    location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|css)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           30d;
        add_header Pragma "public";
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {            
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV magana;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $folder.magana.dev.hexis.fr;
   }
location /app {
        alias /var/www/projects/dev/magana/$folder/htdocs/app/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @app;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location @app {
        rewrite /app/(.*)$ /app/public/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
   location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

What i'm missing?
Thanks for your help

Comment: The regular expression locations take precedence over prefix locations. Use the `^~` modifier. Try: `location ^~ /app { ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith... I tryied but without success

Answer (score 0):

Whit this code i can access the application but I still don't find the way to declare e=the kernelrootdirectory

```
server {
  listen 80;

    server_name ~^(?<folder>[^.]*).magana.dev.example.fr;


    charset utf-8;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    set $symfonyRoot /var/www/projects/dev/magana/$folder/htdocs/app/public;
        set $symfonyScript index.php;

    root /var/www/projects/dev/magana/$folder/htdocs;
    access_log /var/www/projects/dev/magana/$folder/access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/projects/dev/commons/logs/magana_error.log;

    client_max_body_size 200M;

    location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp$
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           30d;
        add_header Pragma "public";
    }
    location /app {
                root $symfonyRoot;
                rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
                try_files $uri @symfonyFront;
        }
    location @symfonyFront {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $symfonyRoot/$symfonyScript;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /app/$symfonyScript;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /app$uri?$args;
        }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV magana;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $folder.magana.dev.hexis.fr;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```